# How to write this correctly with codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im trying to write a function to update password with codeigniter and here is the code

```
public function changepass(){
    $password = md5( $this->_clean($_POST['Password']) );
    $data = array(
       'Password' => $password
    );        
    $this->db->update('users', $data, array('UserName' => $_POST[UserName]));
}
```

this updates the database but still throwing a message

```
Severity: Notice
Message: Use of undefined constant UserName - assumed 'UserName'
```

how to prevent this message and also how to check whether query executes successfully or not and echo a message "success" in this case?

Comment: I might be missing something, but do you validate if $_POST['UserName'] is the username of the current user? If not, what stops me from posting your username with password of my choice and then log in into your account? IMHO you should not use $_GET/$_POST in such scenario at all - you should obtain the user to update from the session.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `$_POST[UserName]` to `$this->input->post('UserName')` as long as you are in controller. This does not work in model. CodeIgniter also destroys $_POST array.

`$this->db->affected_rows()` should return 1 for success.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i tried $this->db->affected_rows(), if the user type same pass as before this returns 0. that means query not executed?

Comment: I guess it is executed but nothing changes, means affecting 0 rows. I suggest you using ids instead of strings to identify users data as well.